# Android: compose drawArc would not get centered within `Box`

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am trying to show progress using `drawArc` for compose. I have tried `drawBehind` modifier to draw a background circle and not trying to draw another circle on top of it to show the progress. The problems is, no matter what I try, the arc turns out to be drawn at top left corner all the time. If I explicitly define the `topLeft` value, it only works for 1 screen size. So I am trying to get a dynamic size for both circles and also the strokewidth. So for Tablets only the circles should be increased depending on the screensize and also the thickness should be increased for the same. And for the smaller size devices, the value should be decreasing. Here is my code and output:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow),
        ) {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier
                .size(maxWidth, maxHeight)
                .background(color = Color.Red)) {
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    radius = (maxWidth /4).toPx(),
                    style = Stroke(width = 14f, cap = StrokeCap.Round),
                )
                val sweepAngle = progress/100 * 360
                drawArc(
                    size = Size((maxWidth/2).toPx(),(maxWidth/2).toPx()),
                    color = Color.Green,
                    startAngle = -90f,
                    sweepAngle = sweepAngle,
                    useCenter = false,
                    style = Stroke(10f, cap = StrokeCap.Round),
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

PS: I cannot use another circle object since I need to have the tip of the circle round aka cap should be Stroke.Round.

I ended up trying `BoxWithConstraints` so I can have access to `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to calculate the topLeft offset of the arc as `center of the circle - radius of the circle`.
Then the size of arc is `maxWidth/2` instead of `maxWidth/4 = radius`.

Something like:

```
            val stroke = 5.dp
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Gray,
                radius = (maxWidth /4).toPx(),
                style = Stroke(width = stroke.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
            )

            val sweepAngle = progress/100 * 360
            val offsetx = this.center.x - (maxWidth/4).toPx() 
            val offsety = this.center.y - (maxWidth/4).toPx() 

            drawArc(
                size = Size((maxWidth/2).toPx(),(maxWidth/2).toPx()),
                color = Color.Green,
                startAngle = 0f,
                sweepAngle = -sweepAngle,
                topLeft = Offset(offsetx,offsety),
                useCenter = false,
                style = Stroke(stroke.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
            )
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I quickly tested it, seems like this is the piece that I was missing. Thanks a lot! I will implement the whole thing and check every other use-case.